# How to bundle and run es6 module in browser

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to run es6 module library in my application which i am trying to run in browser.
Below is app.js code which i want to run in the browser.

```
import BpmnModdle from 'bpmn-moddle';
function hello(){
    var moddle = new BpmnModdle
    var xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
    '<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" id="1234"><bpmn:process id="1234"><bpmn:startEvent id="2" name="StartEvent"><bpmn:outgoing>5</bpmn:outgoing></bpmn:startEvent><bpmn:task id="3" name="Task"><bpmn:outgoing>6</bpmn:outgoing><bpmn:incoming>5</bpmn:incoming></bpmn:task><bpmn:endEvent id="4" name="EndEvent"><bpmn:incoming>6</bpmn:incoming></bpmn:endEvent><bpmn:sequenceFlow id="5" name="" source="2" target="3"/><bpmn:sequenceFlow id="6" name="" source="3" target="4"/></bpmn:process><mxGraphModel><root><Workflow label="MyWorkflow" description="" href="" id="0"><mxCell/></Workflow><Layer label="Default Layer" id="1"><mxCell parent="0"/></Layer><Start label="StartEvent" id="2"><mxCell style="symbol;image=images/symbols/event.png;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="150" y="200" width="80" height="60" as="geometry"/></mxCell></Start><Task label="Task" description="" href="" id="3"><mxCell style="symbol;image=images/task.PNG" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="340" y="190" width="100" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell></Task><End label="EndEvent" id="4"><mxCell style="symbol;image=images/symbols/event_end.png" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="550" y="200" width="80" height="60" as="geometry"/></mxCell></End><Edge label="" id="5"><mxCell style="straightEdge" edge="1" parent="1" source="2" target="3"><mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/></mxCell></Edge><Edge label="" id="6"><mxCell style="straightEdge" edge="1" parent="1" source="3" target="4"><mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/></mxCell></Edge></root></mxGraphModel></bpmn:definitions>';
    moddle.fromXML(xmlStr, function(err, definitions) {


        console.log(definitions)

        // add a root element
        var bpmnProcess = moddle.create('bpmn:Process', { id: 'MyProcess_1' });
        definitions.get('rootElements').push(bpmnProcess);
        moddle.toXML(definitions, function(err, xmlStrUpdated) {
          // xmlStrUpdated contains new id and the added process
          console.log(xmlStrUpdated)
        });

      });
}
hello()
```

To compile the app.js i have used babel. below is my babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }
```

And i am getting the output in console.
But when i try to run the file in the browser i am getting the error as
"require is not defined"

I have also tried to add webpack.config.js file to bundle the project. below is my webpack.config.js and the html file.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
};
```

html file.

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
<script src="./dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After doing this i am getting the error as file not found. can someone help me in understanding how to bundle and run the file in the browser

Comment: try setting targets in babel config: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage#configuration

Comment: You are supposed to actually build this first using the `npm` command. Go through any webpack tutorial first, you are missing many fundamental steps here.

Comment: i did build the file using npm . "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files",    That how i am getting th output in the terminal. but not in the browser